# Why does the C preprocessor insert an extra space?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

When I run the C preprocessor on this source file:

```
1+1 1-1
A+1 A-1
A+A A-A
#define A 1
A+1 A-1
A+A A-A
```

I get this output with `clang -E -P`:

```
1+1 1-1
A+1 A-1
A+A A-A

1 +1 1 -1
1 +1 1 -1
```

And almost exactly the same output with `gcc -E -P`:

```
1+1 1-1
A+1 A-1
A+A A-A
1 +1 1 -1
1 +1 1 -1
```

I know the behavior of the C preprocessor used as a stand alone tool is not specified by the C Standard, but what is the reason for both `gcc` and `clang` to insert an extra space after the expansion of the macro `A` when followed by a `+` or a `-` operator?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Token-Spacing.html

Comment: It's probably to avoid creating output with `++`, which would be an post-increment or pre-increment operator.